# window.enableMouseFlow is undefined in componentDidMount() but available in render()

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Hi I have this piece of code

```
    export class CompanyAccountsList extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        getChildContext() {
            return { prefix: 'company_accounting' };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            //getting window.enableMouseFlow in this console
            console.log(window);

            //can't get window.enableMouseFlow in this console
            console.log(window.enableMouseFlow);

            if (window.enableMouseFlow) {
                //This codes are never executing as the condition is undefined
                enableMouseFlow();
                setMouseFlowTag('new_company_accounting');
            }
        }

        render() {
    //Rendering codes are here
    }
```

On initial load of the page I am getting the result as

```
Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …} CompanyAccountsList.jsx?a48a:36
undefined
```

In the consoled 'window object' 'enableMouseFlow' is available but when I am trying to get it as console.log(window.enableMouseFlow); it is consoling as 'undefined'

If I console it in the render() method I am getting the result as:

```
ƒ () {
          sessionStorage.setItem('mf_start', '1');
          activateMouseflow();
      }
```

So as summation, I can't find 'window.enableMouseFlow' in the componentDidMount()

Answer (score 1):

I think `console.log` is passing a reference to window, and so it may be resolved at the time of it's actual log to the console. 
You could try

`const x = JSON.stringify(window);
console.log(x);` 
(I think that'd give you window at the time of componentDidMount)

But I'm guessing that enablemouseflow is something that gets added to `window` after the creation of the page in some other script, so it's not actually available for this component. (but would be available at render).

Answer (score 0):

@Alan Yes actually I'm getting window in componentDidMount, even If I console window I can get enableMouseFlow in console.

```
console.log(window);

Output: 
//window.enableMouseFlow is available
```

but if I only console window.enableMouseFlow I'm getting it as undefined

```
console.log(window.enableMouseFlow);

Output:
//Undefined
////window.enableMouseFlow is not available
```

Secondly, yes I am thinking same as you enablemouseflow is gets added to window after the creation of the page in some other script but I have some other similar reactJs pages where I can get console.log(window.enableMouseFlow) in the componentDidMount

FYI, after populating the page in the browser console I can get console.log(window.enableMouseFlow);

Actually window.enablemouseflow is loading a bit later actually, see the screenshot:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgUBj.png)

Comment: Hmm... so, we're agreed on what's happening. window.enableMouseFlow is being loaded later (maybe in a sibling component to this one, and other components may have that enablemouseflow enabler as their parent component, which is why it's in the constructor for them).


It seems like anything you want to do with `window.enableMouseFlow` you could just happen in `render()` no?